# NSKeyedUnarchiever loading line makes App crash on start

Tags: ios, loading, save, nskeyedarchiver

I have a problem with loading an Object with NSKeyedUnarchiever.
My Object is a NSDictionary, which contains several Objects like Arrays and some of my own. They all conform to the NSCoding Protocol.

I save my Object like this:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myDictionary toFile:path];
```

If I load the Object in the same run with this code:

```
myDictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
```

everything works.
But when I quit the App and open it again, it crashes right at this Line.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your save is successful:

```
if (![NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myDictionary toFile:path])
{
    // saving failed for some reason
    return;
}
```

Also make sure the file exists before trying to unarchive it:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
{
    // file does not exist at path (deleted?)
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
It wasn't the solution, but it helped me to figure it out.  
In one of my classes I tried to save the view property, which messed everything up.
After fixing that everything works now. :)

Martin Lücke